# Nhibernate mapping clarification wrt Map using entities

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

When using a mapping such as:

```
<class name="Product">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="guid" />
  </id>
  <property name="Name"/>
  <map name="UserAddedFields" table="UserAddedFields" >
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <index-many-to-many column="UserAddedFieldId" class="UserAddedField"/>
    <element column="fieldValue"/>
  </map>
</class>
```

And I wanted to add a new UserAddedField to an existing Product I need to first save the UserAddedField or I will get a TransientObjectException. The exception seems to imply I could set a cascade action that would make it autosave but nothing I've tried seems to work. Is this not possible?

///////////////////////////////////////////////

After the suggestion below I've changed the mapping to the following but I'm getting a StaleStateException:  Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

```
      <class name="Product">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name"/>
    <bag name="UserAddedFields" lazy="true" inverse="true" batch-size="25" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="parentId" />
      <one-to-many class="UserAddedFieldSetting" />
    </bag>
  </class>
  <class name="UserAddedField" >
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="IsGlobal" type="bool"/>
  </class>
  <class name="UserAddedFieldSetting" >
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="FieldValue" />
    <many-to-one class="Product" name="Product" />
    <many-to-one class="UserAddedField" name="UserAddedField" cascade="all"/>
  </class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already experienced, *cascading* is not supported on the `index` element/mapping. While elements like

- [Map](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Cfg/MappingSchema/HbmMap.cs) or
- [ManyToOne](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Cfg/MappingSchema/HbmManyToOne.cs)

do support `cascade`, the [`index-many-to-many`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Cfg/MappingSchema/HbmIndexManyToMany.cs) is just another index, which nature is not intended to be cascade supporting.

My suggestion would be: do not use the map. Introduce brand new object instead, represented by table `UserAddedFields`. If we'd extend it with a surrogated primary key, we can have an object like:

```
public class UserAddedFieldSetting
{
   public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

   public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
   public virtual UserAddedField UserAddedField { get; set; }
   public virtual decimal FieldValue { get; set; }
```

which can be mapped as a `<bag>`, i.e: `IList<UserAddedFieldSetting>`. Not only it will support cascading on the `many-to-one` mapping of the `UserAddedField`, but also the querying will be much more simple and straightforward

```
<bag name="UserAddedFields" lazy="true" inverse="true" 
     batch-size="25" 
     cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="parent_id" />
  <one-to-many class="UserAddedFieldSetting" />
</bag>
```

EXTEND:

So, now, we have a mapping *(see updated part in the question)*, which is working as needed - well *almost*. The issue is, that NHibernate is executing the `SaveOrUpdate()` on our `many-to-one` relation.

The problem here is, how to decide, that `SaveOrUpdate` should INSERT or UPDATE? And NHibernate decided to UPDATE by the way... but the row count returned was 0. Because there was in fact **no** row to update. We need to insert.

The key to the answer is in the mapping of the "unsaved value", the value representing the new == *"to be inserted"* state.

So let's extend the mapping:

```
<class name="UserAddedField" >
  <id name="Id" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
    <generator class="guid" />
  </id>
  ...
```

And be sure, that every new C# instance of the `UserAddedField` has the

```
Id = Guid.Empty;
```

Now, NHibernate, when the SaveOrUpdate is called, will know, that `Guid.Empty` means do INSERT...

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is exactly what I want, but I still cant seem to get it to work. I've included the mapping I'm using in the original message. Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've extended the answer, with description what is happening. We only need to learn NHibernate how to correctly decide if the `UserAddeField` is existing *(should be updated due to `cascade`)* or INSERTED

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, you nailed it. In my case however, setting unsaved-value was not needed. It was actually UserAddedFieldSetting that was causing the Update/Insert confusion. The mistake was in my test set up, When I created the new UserAddedFieldSetting object I foolishly assigned it an Id.